# Create a dynamic dropdown menu in Microsoft Form

Tags: microsoft-forms

I'm trying to make a Microsoft Form and want to have a dropdown menu for one of the questions.  I was wondering if it was possible to have an add feature where recipients could add an answer to the drop down menu if they don't see what they're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Once you click the question type to be 'Choice', then right after the last option box there's a link/button 'Add "Other" option'. Click on it and then select the three dots on the bottom right corner and select 'Dropdown'.